# Where to put methods which deem to be shared for whole app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

By default, rails app shares all helper methods for views. Any helper methods is automatically shared among all views and this may cause naming conflict or confusing if the application gets big. There are some methods which deem to be shared for the whole app. How to share and where to put those "global" methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is normally no need for "global" methods, due to the fact that Rails is based on Ruby which is an object-oriented language. Rails is implementing MVC in a strong way which is an object-oriented pattern as well.

But if you need to place code that is globally accessible, you are free to use Ruby that allows that by extending any class. So by using

```
class Object
   def my_global_method
     ...
   end
end
```

this will be available everywhere *if loaded*. Reading the ["Rails Guide on Configuration"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) I think the natural place is to require the file you have added in `config/application.rb`. Another option could be to place the file in the directory `config/initializers`, so it will be loaded automatically after Rails is initialized.

Comment: Currently we put the "global" methods in sessions_helper.rb and include SessionsHelper in application_controller.rb. We can use the methods from anywhere in myapp.                 If adding the methods in config/application.rb . Is the code added within module myapp  Class Application << Rails::Application ?

Comment: Global means global: each object has access. With your approach, every view and controller has access, but no model objects. And no, it is not in any module.